# What is the use case of ActivityCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate Interface in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions, androidx

I found this `ActivityCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate` interface while exploring android source code related to android runtime permission.

What I was looking for it I wanted to handle permission model in a custom class by somehow handling `OnRequestPermissionsResult` in a custom class rather than in `Activity` or `Fragment`.

This `ActivityCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate` has two methods:

```
// 1
abstract boolean onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 

// 2
abstract boolean requestPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode)
```

The 1st one made sense to me and I got to know from docs that we can use it to delegate permission requests and handle it in this method.

However I was unable to understand what docs says about the second method. I cannot find any use case for that.

You can check full documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate.html

Can anybody tell me for what this interface is used and how can we use it to handle permissions in a custom class?